# Why won't my 2 buttons centre in Div?

Tags: html, css

I've tried so many solutions, it's giving me a headache!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* Global */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

button {
  background-color: #ff5f49;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

/* Navigation */

header {
  background-color: #353c42;
  min-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff
}

/* Jumbotron */

#jumbotron {

}

#jumbotron img {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.button-1 {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Clearfix */

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Digital Creative Agency Melbourne">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Creative Agency Melbourne">
  <meta name="author" content="KreativeZ">
  <title>KreativeZ | Creative Agency Melbourne</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Our Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section id="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="img/KreativeZ_logo.png" alt="KreativeZ Logo">
      <div class="container">
      <button class="button-1" type="button">Get in touch!</button>
      <button class="button-1" type="button">See Our Work</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add ' text-align: center;' to the container.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* Global */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  background-color: #ff5f49;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

/* Navigation */

header {
  background-color: #353c42;
  min-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff
}

/* Jumbotron */

#jumbotron {

}

#jumbotron img {
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.button-1 {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Clearfix */

.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Digital Creative Agency Melbourne">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Creative Agency Melbourne">
  <meta name="author" content="KreativeZ">
  <title>KreativeZ | Creative Agency Melbourne</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Our Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section id="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="img/KreativeZ_logo.png" alt="KreativeZ Logo">
      <div class="container">
      <button class="button-1" type="button">Get in touch!</button>
      <button class="button-1" type="button">See Our Work</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider it the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe it was that simple. Absolute legend.

Comment: Welcome. Glad that I could help. If you think this solved the problem, kindly mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You might add `display:flex` and `justify-content:center` to the container of your buttons:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* Global */
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container .container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  background-color: #ff5f49;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

/* Navigation */

header {
  background-color: #353c42;
  min-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

nav ul li {
```

```html
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Our Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section id="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="img/KreativeZ_logo.png" alt="KreativeZ Logo">
      <div class="container">
      <button class="button-1" type="button">Get in touch!</button>
      <button class="button-1" type="button">See Our Work</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```